# Prove: For every a and b integers and every m positive integer, if a ≡ b (mod m), then a² ≡ b² (mod m).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could you help me solve this theorem? I don't understand how I can taste him.

Prove: For every a and b integers and every m positive integer, if a ≡ b (mod m), then a² ≡ b² (mod m).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, so, if $m\mid a-b,$ then $m\mid a^2-b^2$

Comment: $(b+mk)^2=b^2+2bmk+m^2k^2=b^2+m(2bk+mk^2)$.

Comment: This is a particular case of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879251/divisibility-by-7-rule-and-congruence-arithmetic-laws/879262#879262)

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418681/prove-or-disprove-for-all-positive-integers-n-and-for-all-integers-a-and-b-if)

Comment: If $a = b + mk$ then $a^2 = (b+ mk)^2 = b^2 + 2bmk + m^2k^2$.